# What is the best way to have a css optimized with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, pagespeed

What is better?: to write your own css to give padding and margin to the components of your website or use the spacing helpers of Bootstrap 4?

For example. **Option A**:

```
<div class="header-item">
    <a href="contact">
        <div class="item-info">
            <img class="img-icon" src="help.svg" alt="Contact">

        </div>
        <div class="header-item-txt">
            <div><strong>Contact</strong></div>
            <div class="sub-txt">+36 343 434 343</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Styles for .header-item class in **Option A**:

```
.header-item {
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Or **Option B**. Remove padding styles from css and use bootstrap helpers:

```
<div class="header-item px-1 pt-2 pb-2">
 ... content
</div>
```

And css from **Option B**:

```
.header-item {
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

What's the best way?

Comment: best to use Bootstrap Utilities readymade helper https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/ i.e. your `option B`. or can make your own css mixin extending the same. like https://gist.github.com/jacurtis/30da4bf9a6c9b9b5cc0aebac512ca7c9

Answer (score 0):

If you install bootstrap to your site **best way to use their declaretion**.

**WHY?**

Probably you will have to use `!important` to override bootstrap whats inefficient

[when using `!important is right choice`](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: the problem I see in using bootstrap helpers is that each html element has too many classes and it is good practice not to have more than 4 classes per html element.

Comment: no! that the way bootstrap work better use alot of bootstrap classes then your own css

Comment: I'm not agree with !important part. If you will important it earlier then you styles, it will not be needed to use important in most cases. I recommend to use SCSS for development, you can import everything you need without not needed modules and code

Answer (score 0):

IMO, as `bootstrap` files are already loaded, It is better to use their predefined classes written in bootstrap.

So, in your example what I think is using **Option B** is better than writing a new class on your own and wait for it to load.

```
<div class="header-item px-1 pt-2 pb-2">
 ... content
</div>
```

Comment: the problem I see in using bootstrap helpers is that each html element has too many classes and it is good practice not to have more than 4 classes per html element.